# A struggle with jets and Grothendieck vs Ehresmann connections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, connections

Let $X\to Y$ be a $C^\infty$ submersion. Consider the following two sheaves.

1. The sheaf on $Y$ comprised of jets of sections of $X\to Y$.
2. The sheaf on $X$ given by the quotient of $\Delta_{X/Y}^{-1}C^\infty_{X\times_YX}$ by the second power of the ideal of $C^\infty$ maps about the diagonal vanishing on the diagonal.

Consider the following three definitions of a connection on the submersion $X\to Y$.

1. Let $J^1_{X/Y}\to Y$ be the bundle of 1-jets of sections of $X\to Y$. Retaining the constant term of a Taylor expansion gives a bundle map $J^1_{X/Y}\to X$ over $Y$. A connection on $X\to Y$ is a section of this bundle map.
2. Write $\Delta^{(1)}_{Y}$ for the locally ringed space structure on the underlying topological space of $Y$ with structure sheaf given by the above quotient of $\Delta_{Y}^{-1}C^\infty_{Y\times Y}$. It comes with two canonical *locally ringed space* projections $p_1,p_2:\Delta_{Y}^{(1)}\rightrightarrows Y$. A *Grothendieck connection on $X\to Y$* is an isomorphism between the pullbacks (in the category of locally ringed spaces) of $X\to Y$ along $p_1,p_2$ which restricts to the identity on the diagonal.
3. An *Ehresmann connection on $f:X\to Y$* is a section of the differential $\mathrm df:\mathrm TX\to f^\ast \mathrm TY$ (in the category of $C^\infty$ vector bundles over $X$).

---

I understand the equivalence of the first and third definitions. For instance, starting with a connection in the sense of the first definition, an Ehresmann connection can be constructed using derivatives of local sections of $X\to Y$.

**Question.** How are Grothendieck connections related/equivalent to the first/third definition?

**Added.** For what it's worth, an explicit construction of pullbacks in the category of locally ringed spaces is sketched in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/322400). In particular, it seems that on stalks, a Grothendieck connection would give an automorphism of the stalk $(C_{X,x}^\infty\otimes_{C^\infty_{Y,y}}\mathcal O_{\Delta^{(1)}_Y,y})_\mathfrak q$ where $fx=y$ and $\mathfrak q$ is a prime ideal which pulls back to the maximal ideals of $C_{X,x}^\infty,\mathcal  O_{\Delta^{(1)}_Y,y}$. The structure sheaf of the first neighborhood of the diagonal of $Y$ consists of 1-jets of real $C^\infty$ map on $Y$, so in coordinates its stalk is isomorphic to the ring of dual numbers $\mathbb R[\varepsilon_1,\dots \varepsilon _{\dim Y}]$. Even on this level of stalks I don't know how to relate to a section of $\mathrm df:\mathrm TX\to X\times_Y\mathrm TY$, though the explicit construction of the pullback in $\mathsf{LRS}$ hints at viewing tangents as derivations.

Comment: I suppose $k=1$?

Comment: Yes. Removed that bit.

Comment: It might be useful to look at this question and its answers. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68305/grothendieck-connections-and-jets?rq=1

Comment: Dear @TomGoodwillie I spent a while there but wasn't able to relate to Ehresmann connections.